# Checkin/Checkout a file using Microsoft Graph Client Library

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I want to checkout/checkin a file on my OneDrive for Business using Microsoft Graph Client Library, I see the api calls for checkin/checkout

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_checkin

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_checkout

But I am unable to find a way to do the same via the library.

Comment: This feature (as of 8/13/2018) is only available on the beta endpoint. The Microsoft Graph client libraries target the v1.0 endpoint. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Thank you for replying. We are working on dotnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Mainer posted in comments, the latest Microsoft Graph client libraries just support the version 1.0 of the APIs. Meanwhile the API endpoint for check in file and check out file is only available on the beta.

If we want use these APIs, we can only complete the HTTP request by ourselves.

For more detail, you can find it in [the issue on the GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/108).